# APEX 5: How to edit dynamically chart xml?

Tags: xml, charts, oracle-apex-5

I am building an Apex Application with a couple of charts (html rendered barchart from the wizard). Now, I have to include two important features. Change the colour of the bars depending on the value and include some labels on top or after the bars.
I know that this can be achieved by setting the option "Custom xml" to YES and editing the xml. The problem is that I have not been able to edit this dynamically.

I have tried to execute a function in the xml area, but it gets interpreted as a String(I guess the area is treated like a template). I have also tried to add an item, reference to it in the xml and add the generated text to the item trough a PL/SQL block, but this also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution based on SVG format understanding. Here is an example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=34599:4 It contains a chart with bars and a button (`To Red`). Button's action is Dynamic action, which executes a javascript code. If you click the button, one of bars will change its color.

How does it work. SVG grafics works the same way as HTML and CSS. Tag `defs` inside the `svg` tag contains a list of styles, tags `g`, `path`, `rect` and many others contain graphics, which can use styles from the `defs` list. You need to change predefined `defs` list and graphics elements.

Here is the code. I am not a good javascript programmer, and, as you can see, all significant values are hardcoded here. But I hope the whole idea is clear:

```
// here we get defs list. Be careful if you have several charts on the page:
var defs = document.getElementsByTagName("defs")[0];

// here we get one of color styles:
var grad1 = document.getElementById("#ac_linearGradient_75");

// make a copy of the style:
var grad2 = grad1.cloneNode(true);

// and change its ID:
grad2.id = grad2.id + "_copy";

// then define new color:
grad2.firstChild.setAttribute("style", "stop-color:rgb(209, 29, 29);stop-opacity:0.9");

// append to the defs list:
defs.appendChild(grad2);

// get one of bars by ID:    
var bar1 = document.getElementById("#ac_path_8o");

// set new filling style:
bar1.setAttribute("fill", "url(##ac_linearGradient_75_copy)");
```

In Dynamic Action's properties you can set property `Fire on page load` - code will work automatically after page load. Also in javascript code you can get values from items, put them into the chart, etc.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i will look into it. I guess you can add this way some labels to the chart as well.

Comment: @Alexsen I still don't know how does AnyChart add a text into the chart. But you can add a text using `text` tag. See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_text.asp

Comment: Well I cant get any bar from the html document because the only tag  they have is a class and it has a white space in the name so I cant get the element. It was a good idea, it didn't work for me but it may work for others.

Comment: @Alexsen Class names can't have spaces inside. If you see spaces, this is two (or more) classes. Anyway, if you want to try this way, you should create another question about this new problem. I'm new to HTML/CSS/javascript/SVG, I know just several tricks.