# Highlight point in Oracle APEX chart

Tags: oracle-apex-5, anychart

I have a chart in Oracle APEX app and I need to highlight one point, for example point *x = 5*.

[image]

When adding a new series with one point using SQL query `SELECT...WHERE X=5` I've got a point on my chart, but it has `x = 1`. How can I highlight point using only one series or is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932253/apex-5-how-to-edit-dynamically-chart-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is following. Main series query (for example):

```
select null, rownum * rownum val, rownum r
  from dual
connect by level < 10
```

Additional series query:

```
select null, case when rownum = 5 then 25 else null end val, 
rownum r
from dual
connect by level < 10
```

The additional series gives null values everywhere but desired value in the desired position. Also it has the same labels (third column of the query) and the same count of rows. The page with this example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=34599:10